# Prevent status = failed in chrome while loading multiple html5 videos

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video, popcornjs

I am loading multiple html5 video elements onto a page in webm format. I intermittently receive  status failed errors for the videos in which playback stops. Has anyone encountered this issue? and know how to prevent it?

I tried to append the html for the video tags at an 1 second interval but that did not prevent the problem for occuring.

I am also using popcorn.js to set cues in each of the videos and I'm wondering if that could be related to the errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was hitting the browser's limit of simultaneous request to a single url. The solution was to set up subdomains www1. www2 etc that point back to the root url.  This technique is called sharding.